# Incompatibility between beamer and pdfrender packages?

Tags: beamer, color, pdf

I have problems compiling a `beamer` presentation that I wrote and used two years ago.  As the code hasn't changed, I guess some update must be the culprit.  (I'm using MiKTeX on Windows with all updates installed as of today.)  I was able to boil down the problem to the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pdfrender}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the following error message:

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `.'.
l.307 \PdfRender@PatchColor
```

It seems `pdfrender` and `beamer` don't work together anymore.  What am I supposed to do?

Comment: This should be resolved by the pdfrender package. I opened an issue at https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/94.

Comment: I uploaded a new version to ctan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To work around the problem, you could switch to an older version of the latex kernel:

```
\RequirePackage[2023/11/10]{latexrelease}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pdfrender}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Or you could switch back to an older xcolor version:

```
\RequirePackage{xcolor}[=v2]
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pdfrender}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```